# CKEditor - client side spell checker

Tags: winforms, ckeditor, client-side

CKEditor supports by default server side spell checker. There is any solution to integrate a client-side spell checker?

P.S. I'm using CKEditor in a WinForms application.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into this which enables Aspell for CKEditor:

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15893